# how to bind data from database to select tag of html using jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me out in binding data from database to select tag of html using jquery 
with an example.

My requirement is to get one column from database table named 'Purpose' (consists of records such as lunch, pizza, tea, coffee etc..) into select tag either by using jquery or javascript.
I tried binding values to control from code behind but with `runat=server` property. I want to bind the same without using `runat=server` property, but by using jquery or javascript.

Looking forward for reply..

Answer (score 1):

To populate a `<select>` with jQuery with data from an external url:

```
var url = "path/to/some/json/resource"; // the url to load data from.
$.getJSON( url, function(result) {
    var $select = $('#myDropDown'); // the <select> element.
    $select.empty(); // probably want to clear before populating.
    $.each(result, function() {
        // append an <option> for each item in returned list.
        select.append($("<option></option>").attr(result.PurposeId).text(result.Name)); 
    });
});
```

You would probably want to load data from a WebAPI, IHttpHandler etc, where you can specify the returned format.